# Limit the number of scenario to run in parallel - testng - cuccumber

Tags: selenium, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Thanks in advance.

I had create an UI BDD framework and using testNG as a runner.
Problem I am facing is , I have 3 feature file with in total 12 scenario so far , so when I run in parallel , 12 browser open up , because of which I am getting timeout exception , I tried to search entire www , and done changes in my pom file but still same.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/ParallelRun.java</include>
                </includes>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                <forkCount>3</forkCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Runner Class

```
public class ParallelRun extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
@Override
@DataProvider(parallel = true)
public Object[][] scenarios() {
    return super.scenarios();
}
```

}

Comment: Please share your runner class

Comment: Have you gone through this https://ghchirp.tech/466/  ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the core of your problem is not in `surefire` config but in your tests.

Anyway I would rework your configuration to be (which has to limit your threads to `3`)

```xml
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>**/ParallelRun.java</include>
    </includes>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
            <value>3</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</configuration>
```

According to [cucumber documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/#testng) you need to have `parallel=classes` only if you have several test runners.

Forks are also not applicable here. According to [surefire plugin doc](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) forks with `parallel=classes` do not make sense since forks themselves process classes in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Scenarios will be executed in parallel, so please decrease your thread count to 1.

```
<threadCount>1</threadCount>
```

> if you are using **TDD**, use thread count.
> if you are using **BDD via
> cucumber** file, **do not use thread count** - set as 1 thread count.